# using ATSPI2 & DBus in a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, dbus, ubuntu-22.04, appium-desktop

I am trying to perform GUI tests on docker container.

In docker image with Ubuntu 22.04 I install **xvfb** and also using following commands to run the desktop.

`ENV DISPLAY=:0 CMD ["Xvfb", ":0", "-screen", "0", "1920x1080x24+32"]`

I am able to run any of the GUI applications on the docker container, also has VNC connection. There is no ubuntu-desktop, it is just a black screen with the GUI application running.

How can I configure DBus&ATSPI2 interface in Dockerfile?

When I try to use @stdspa/appium-linux-driver, the following error returns from the driver.

"AT-SPI: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus. Is at-spi-bus-launcher running?"